# Всегда ли обособляются определения, оторванные от определяемого слова?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, определения

Как известно, такое правило есть в справочнике у Розенталя, но что-то мне помнится, что я очень часто встречал отсутствие обособления в таких случаях; к тому же у Лопатина такого в справочнике нет, у него написано, что обособляются в случае отрыва от определяемого слова только распространенные определения. Что думаете по этому поводу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) С точки зрения грамматики**

Определение, **стоящее на расстоянии от определяемого слова обособляется всегда**, причем любое (согласованное и несогласованное, распространенное и нераспространенное). Это информация из грамматики.

Почему? А как вы себя представляете синтаксическую связь согласования на расстоянии? Определение может стоять перед определяемым словом и после определяемого слова, но только не на расстоянии, так как это **присловная связь**.

А вот при обособлении присловная связь нарушается, обособленный член больше **не образует словосочетания** с подчиняющим словом. Поэтому допускается его дистантное расположение. У Лопатина просто не указана эта информация, это более краткий справочник.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

3) если оторвано в тексте от существительного: *Глаза смыкались и, **полузакрытые**, тоже улыбались (Т.); На лавке, **разбросанные**, лежали поршни, ружьё (Л. Т.); Настасья Петровна ещё раз обняла Егорушку, обозвала его ангельчиком и, **заплаканная**, стала собирать на стол (Ч.);*

**2) С точки зрения актуального членения**

При актуальном членении предложения по принципу "тема – рема, предмет – сообщение о предмете)  пользователь делает с ним всё, что хочет.

Иначе говоря, он расставляет слова по своему усмотрению, ориентируясь на **логическое выделение нужных слов**. Поэтому может получиться и так: определение в начале предложения, а определяемое слово в конце.

В то же время автор рассчитывает на понимание со стороны читателя и старается исключить какую-либо двусмысленность.

**3) И что тогда делать?**

Я предлагаю  применить **метод грамматической реконструкции**: *Я себе воздвиг нерукотворный памятник.* Ничего не обособляется? Значит, так тому и быть.

А вы что предлагаете? **Как помочь Розенталю исправить правило, чтобы не было таких вопросов?**

И вот еще замечание. Такие"вольности" мы наблюдаем **внутри простого неосложненного предложения**, поэтому понять и восстановить его грамматику не так сложно.

**А это текст из грамматики:** Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка" Курс лекций, 2013 год

https://fileskachat.com/view/23942_22ad6bd46d5806a1491e0c14767bc8f6.html

6. Обособляется **любое  определение, дистантно расположенное относительно  определяемого  слова**:  Звуки  доносились из леса,  протяжные, загадочные

Comment: Я дополняю ответ с учетом сообщения slava1947. Надеюсь, другие участники тоже не останутся в стороне и дадут свой ответ или комментарий.

Answer (score 2):

> Всегда ли обособляются определения, оторванные от определяемого слова?

**Конечно, не всегда.**

***Удивительный*** Вы задали **вопрос**!

В выделенном мной курсивом предложении определение *удивительный* оторвано от слова *вопрос*, но обособления не требует.

Не требует обособления и определение к слову *памятник* в этой строке Пушкина:

*Я **памятник** себе воздвиг **нерукотворный**...*

> Что думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: Да, согласна, на удивительный вопрос креативный мы получили ответ ( без обособления).

Comment: @slava1947  Мне пришлась очень по душе ваша наблюдательность. Это как раз тот случай, когда становится ясно:  мы привыкли верить правилам, читать поверх строк и делать вид. что мы понимаем написанное. И вот разоблачение такого "понимания" мне лично доставляет удовольствие.Такие моменты очень поучительны и заставляют о многом задуматься.